# EF 6 setting bool in string property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm using EF6 with generic UoW and repository pattern. I'm finding a record from the db by doing:

```
public virtual T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
{
   return dbset.Where(where).FirstOrDefault<T>();
}
```

However, on one entity, I'm getting the following exception. I've checked and rechecked the db, model, dto, etc and property `x` is definitely a string. This is the generated model:

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public int ForeignTableId { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string x { get; set; } // <-- This is the field causing the problem
    public Nullable<bool> IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual ForeignTable ForeignTable { get; set; }
}
```

My controller's action calls the service:

```
MyEntity entity = myEntityService.Get(x => x.Number == param);
```

And the service calls the repository:

```
public MyEntity Get(Expression<Func<MyEntity , bool>> where)
{
    return myEntityRepository.Get(where);
}
```

Is EF messing up or am I missing something else?

> "Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The 'x' property on 'y' could not be set to a 'System.Boolean' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.String'. ","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)\r\n   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)

Comment: Show how you call it and how entity looks. Also don't use repository and UoW as DbContext already implements both.

Comment: With which where clause do you have problem? Show its code please.

Comment: it definitely thinks column `x` is a `bit` in the database. I know you said you checkec, but can you show the table schema?

Comment: It WAS in the database! The entity references a view and this view references a table in another db. When I opened sql statement in query analyzer it was correct. However when I open the view in design mode there were aliases and column 'x' was an alias of deleted! Weird!